# Capturing video of application run during profiling

Tags: c#, .net, automation, ui-automation

I'd like to know if there is a profiling tool that allows capturing a .NET application's run and at the same time capture it's run in a video format.

Afterwards, allowing to scroll through the run stepping through the exact code that was running that moment?

I'm testing a GUI application using automated code, and would like to know exact what code is being executed and compare with what i'm seeing on screen.

Are you aware of such a tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camtasia will do a video screen capture.

Keep in mind a "video" is entirely different than a recording of how code has been executed.  In which case, there's nothing that does both.

If you have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, it has a feature called [IntelliTrace](http://lynk.at/lZSRKm) that sounds like it does most of what you want.

Comment: Camtasia will record, but will still be hard to map "which function am i in now" to what the application is doing/looking like. If a tool that is profiling was also recording, it could map the timing to the exact moment of the run and be able to navigate there

Comment: Camtasia isn't free.  But there are free screencasting software out there.

Comment: Added some detail about IntelliTrace to my answer

Answer (score 1):

There is a free tool called [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) which has a proposed feature called 'Record active Window' (but I don't know if it's implemented in the latest stable release). Check that out to see if you can integrate it to your UI automation.